# Is $c_{00}$ space dense in $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

In our notes there is a question :

> "Show that $\overline {c_{00}}=\ell^{\infty}$ which means $c_{00}$ space is dense in $\ell^{\infty}$

but I have seen that sentence below

> " $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_{0}$ and $\ell^1$ but not in $\ell^{\infty}$ "
>
> $c_{00} =\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} : (x_n)=0 , \forall n\in \mathbb N, \exists N \in \mathbb N\}$

I've tried to show it is dense but I couldn't. My scribbles:

$\overline {c_{00}}=\ell^{\infty}$ iff $\forall x \in \ell^{\infty} ,\exists y_n \in c_{00}, y_n \to x$

-under $\|x\|_{\infty}=\sup|x_n|$ norm-

Let $x=x_n$ $\in \ell^{\infty}$ and  $y_n \in c_{00}$

$x_n=x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_N,...)$  and $y_n=(y_1,y_2,...,y_N,0,0,...)$

$||y_n-x||_{\infty}=\|(y_1-x_1,y_2-x_2,...,y_N-x_N,-x_{N+1},...)\|
_{\infty}=\sup\{|y_1-x_1|,|y_2-x_2|,...,|y_N-x_N|,|-x_{N+1}|,...\}$

Could you please about how should I continue and please correct me if there are mistakes..

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it’s asking about $\ell^\infty$ under the norm topology?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually, there is nothing written norm, metric , any topology etc in question but we are only studying normed spaces in functional analysis courses now. It couldn’t be any other topology. Is it false?

Comment: Yes, it’s false (if we’re using the norm topology). Note, for instance, that the constant sequence $(1,1,1,\dots)$ has distance $1$ from all elements of $c_0$, which is to say that the exterior of $c_0$ contains an open neighborhood.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom then it is closed, isn’t it? About $c_{00}$, could you please give an example for an element which is contained by $\ell^{\infty}$ and isn’t contained by $\overline {c_{00}}$? Thanks

Comment: Yes, $c_0 = \overline{c_{00}}$ is closed as a subspace of $\ell^\infty$.  Since this subspace is not equal to all of $\ell^\infty$, $c_{00}$ is not dense.  The constant sequence which I mention above is an element of $\ell^\infty$ which is not an element of $\overline{c_{00}}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks a lot for your helps :)