# Some questions about $c_{00}$ in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Firstly, we denote
$$
c_{00} = \{\{x_n\}\in\ell^\infty : x_n\not = 0 \hspace{3pt}\text{for a finite number of n's}\}
$$

I would like to find $\overline{c_{00}}$. I tried here:

[Is $c_{00}$ space dense in $\ell^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707983/is-c-00-space-dense-in-ell-infty)

Why is necessarily $c_0 = \overline{c_{00}}$?

Comment: It is in $\ell^\infty$. A constant sequence is bounded.

Comment: What a clumsiness... Sorry, my brain was not working when asking that question and I thought it was $\ell^1$. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$ which contains $c_{00}$. Hence $\overline{c_{00}}\subseteq c_0$.

For the other direction note that if $x=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an element in $c_0$ then for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you can define $y_k=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k,0,0,...)$. Then $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of elements in $c_{00}$, and you can check that $y_k\to x$ in the supremum norm. So $c_0\subseteq\overline{c_{00}}$.

Comment: Clear, thank you.